# Is database replication the way to go to keep production and development databases in sync?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I am not a DBA; however, my small company is using SQL Server for a project that we are working on. On the same SQL Server instance  there is a MS Great Plains (Dynamics GP) database - as we pass data back and forth between the two databases (mainly a scribe process getting our data and transferring it into GP).

We are using database replication (snapshot) as a means of syncing our production and development (and soon DR) environments. Right now its set to replicate every three hours during core business hours - mainly to keep production and development up to date for us while we are working.

1) Is this the correct way of doing such a thing? Is there a better way?
2) Does this stress the server or the SQL Server? Is this a possible cause of GP database issues because they are on the same server and instance?
3) Replication only occurs on the non GP database - this shouldn't affect the GP database at all right?

Our database should stay rather small. In doing the snapshot, it is my understanding that tables get locked while the replication is going on. Do the tables stay locked until the entire replication is done or are they off loading after they are completed as the process continues?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to look into transactional replication. It is set up the same way as snapshot except it sort of keeps a pipe open and pushes or pulls transactions as they occur. Instead of doing somewhat large push and pulls three times a day, transactions are constantly being batched. You only take a penalty when the initial snapshot is being created.

Comment: it can create load on the production server,a way I have done this in the past using a feature called CDC (Change Data Capture) with SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services) to great effect, this would require sql 2008 or newer

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Enterprise or Standard edition? You get more toys to play with in Enterprise.

Comment: The real question is why do you need the dev database to match the prod one? It's actually policy in my company to have only fake data in the dev database... I mean, I ignore that policy but still can't see a need to have nearly real time syncing to dev.

Comment: @DeanOC I believe we have Enterprise.

Comment: @Telos having the real time data in the development database helps us with solving user issues. I think that it is rather important for us to have that data - we keep track of game machines and they often get swapped between locations and its best to have that data in the event that something goes wrong.

Comment: @jharr100 But every three hours? Nightly seems like it would be fine for that. With every three hours you also potentially have the database changing _while_ you're making changes and testing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to sync a SQL Server with another.  There is replication which you are currently using, log shipping, backup/restore, mirroring, and Always On to name a few methods.

The "best" method depends on your requirements.  If you're concerned about disaster recovery, snapshot replication is not a great option and I would look into AlwaysOn Availability Groups.

If load on your production system is a concern I would look into nightly restoring a backup of the production system.

To answer your specific questions:
**1) Is this the correct way of doing such a thing? Is there a better way?**
This answer depends on your exact requirements

**2) Does this stress the server or the SQL Server?**
Doing something is always more work than doing nothing.  Depending on many factors this could affect your production server.

**3) Replication only occurs on the non GP database - this shouldn't affect the GP database at all right?**
Your server only has a finite amount of hardware resources.  It could affect the performance of queries against the GP database

Comment: Going to look into Always on

Answer (score 3):

We have found that having replication in place also adds complexity when it comes to upgrades and schema changes.  If you *must* have dev and prod in sync (and I would argue about that) Always On or log shipping would be my preferred techniques.

DR is a separate issue.  You have to determine your Recovery Point Objective (RPO) and Recovery Time Objective (RTO) and adopt the appropriate technology to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I totally agree with this. I have never understood why replication is not more flexible in regards to changes to articles and or schema. I guess it has to do with checkpoints and whatnot.